# Jmeter Testing shows null message for api links

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing, restful-authentication, jmeter-3.2

How can I handle data from `":/some/api/link"` while I am recording using JMeter it works and when I try it again it shows  "null"  message in 'View results tree'.

Comment: Add your test plan to question

Answer (score 0):

In the majority of cases you won't be able to record and replay you test as modern applications and web APIs normally use dynamic parameters for authentication and security purposes. So most probably your Test Plan should look as follows:

- 1st request

  - Post Processor (in case of REST API it will be [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), in case of SOAP API it will be [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)) to extract any dynamic parameters and save them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
- 2nd request where you should replace hard-coded recorded values with the variables defined in the previous step

The easiest way to detect the dynamic parameters is recording your test 2 times and compare the generated requests, you will need to correlate parameters which differ.

See [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) for more details.